# How to store √ and ✓ (tick mark) symbols

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to store `√` and `✓` symbols in an `nvarchar(50)` column.

Here is code sample

```
vtick.Text = "√";
vvtick.Text = "✓";

INSERT INTO qstnscon (vt,pt) VALUES ('"+vtick.Text+"','"+vvtick.Text+"')";
```

But instead it stores simple characters (e.g. `v`). What is causing this problem?

Comment: What is the collation set to in your database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all - those columns `vt` and `pt` **must be** `NVARCHAR` datatype - otherwise you cannot store those special symbols.

Secondly: when storing Unicode characters, you **MUST** prefix them with a `N'...'` :

```sql
INSERT INTO qstnscon (vt, pt) VALUES (N'"+vtick.Text+"', N'"+vvtick.Text+"')";
                                      ^                  ^
-- these are needed!  ----------------+------------------+
```

Use this technique (prefix with `N`) if you're inserting data from SQL Server Management Studio.

From your C# code: use a **parametrized query**!

```sql
INSERT INTO qstnscon (vt, pt) VALUES (@vt, @pt);
```

and then define them as `SqlParameter` of type `SqlDbType.NVarChar` from C#

```
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO qstnscon (vt, pt) VALUES (@vt, @pt);";

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, yourDbConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@vt", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ".....";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pt", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ".....";

    yourDbConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    yourDbConnection.Close();
}
```